# How to remove a rough line artifact from image after binarization

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, image-thresholding

I am stuck in a problem where I want to differentiate between an object and the [background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5BU7o.jpg)(having a semi-transparent white sheet with backlight) i.e a fixed rough line introduced in the background and is merged with the object. My algorithm right now is I am taking the image from the camera, smoothing with gaussian blur, then extracting Value component from HSV, applying local binarization using wolf method to get the [binarized image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BIfLJ.jpg) after which using OpenCV connected component algorithm I remove some small artifacts that are not connected to object as seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUDon.jpg). Now there is only this line artifact which is merged with the object but I want only the object as seen in this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/drcs9.jpg). Please note that there are 2 lines in the binary image so using the 8 connected logic to detect lines not making a loop is not possible this is what I think and tried also. here is the code for that

```
size = np.size(thresh_img)
skel = np.zeros(thresh_img.shape,np.uint8)
element = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT,(3,3))
done = False

while( not done):
    eroded = cv2.erode(thresh_img,element)
    temp = cv2.dilate(eroded,element)
    temp = cv2.subtract(thresh_img,temp)
    skel = cv2.bitwise_or(skel,temp)
    thresh_img = eroded.copy()

    zeros = size - cv2.countNonZero(thresh_img)
    if zeros==size:
       done = True

# set max pixel value to 1
s = np.uint8(skel > 0)

count = 0
i = 0
while count != np.sum(s):
     # non-zero pixel count
     count = np.sum(s)
     # examine 3x3 neighborhood of each pixel
     filt = cv2.boxFilter(s, -1, (3, 3), normalize=False)
     # if the center pixel of 3x3 neighborhood is zero, we are not interested in it
     s = s*filt
     # now we have pixels where the center pixel of 3x3 neighborhood is non-zero
     # if a pixels' 8-connectivity is less than 2 we can remove it
     # threshold is 3 here because the boxfilter also counted the center pixel
     s[s < 1] = 0
     # set max pixel value to 1
     s[s > 0] = 1
     i = i + 1
```

Any help in the form of code would be highly appreciated thanks.

Comment: Are you familiar with the skeletonization operation? You can use that to remove everything but the loop.

Comment: but doesn't skeletonize just give the outline of an image

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already using connectedComponents the best way is to exclude, not only the ones which are small, but also the ones that are touching the borders of the image.
You can know which ones are to be discarded using `connectedComponentsWithStats()` that gives you also information about the bounding box of each component.

Alternatively, and very similarly you can switch from `connectedComponents()` to `findContours()` which gives you directly the **Components** so you can discard the external ones and the small ones to retrieved the part you are interested in.

Comment: Since the application is realtime so there are some cases when the line may not be touching the border, and now through morphological opereations I have acheived a single line binarizartion.

Comment: Ok, after all writing usable image processing algorithms is more about knowing how the image **will not be** rather considering **how it is**. So that you can expect the algorithm will not be fooled by some inputs.